# Should I use same Enums definitions in ViewModel(UI layer) and domain Model(Business layer)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read about separating domain models and models used to render views. As far as I understand it for every domain model I can(recommended to) create a model in my MVC/UI layer and while bringing data from business layer I populate my UI model. int, float is all fine I just populate them.

How should I handle enums?

should I create a different enum definition all together in my UI layer and then map the enum also while bringing information from my business layer to UI layer? or is it fine having the same enum defined in my business layer to be used in my UI layer as well?

Comment: use the same enum, much less trouble.

Comment: +1 for the question.  This is a good question, but will probably be shut down by SO for eliciting only opinion based answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same enums.  That will reduce confusion, give you just one place to look things up, and make it easier if you ever need to make changes.

The model/view separation is useful for keeping logic unentangled, but using a single set of enums will not impede that.

One exception I would make would be if you needed to keep different parts of your code from sharing headers because you expected to do a lot of conditional compilation or linking, but it doesn't sound like the case here.

Comment: Not necessarily. Assuming the enum is part of your Domain Model if you do use the same one you will be directly coupling your View to your Domain Model.  To me this sounds even worse if instead of binding to a View (through a ViewModel) you were actually exposing the enum through a API contract.  This would mean this Domain Model enum could now potentially be used directly by another system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually enums are int (most of the time) shortcuts.

If you want to use auto dropdownlist's for enums and change the texts, or if you want to "close" your DAL as a project, by example, it may be usefull to make something like

```
public enum ADalEnum : int
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2,
  Three = 3
}
```

...

```
public enum MappedEnum : int
{
  One_Little_Indians = ADalEnum.One,
  Two_Little_Indians = ADalEnum.Two,
  Three_Little_Indians = ADalEnum.Three,
}
```

So it will be "the same".